# How would a graph with edge connectivity 4 ,vertex connectivity 3 and degree of each vertex greater than equal to 5 look like?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Does there exist some algorithms to solve such problems or it needs to be done using trial and error method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like [graph isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) problem or something related to it. However, I can't prove it. I would try to use **constraint-satisfiability** toolkit to solve this task. There are a lot of ways to do it, I'll stick with [satisfiability checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

We can formulate your problem as follows: for given set of vertices and connectivity constraints (edges connectivity, vertices degree, etc) is there any way to select such set of edges that it will satisfy given constraints?

Let's introduce 2 sets of boolean variables: for each vertex and for each edge. Let's agree that if a *variable == True* then it's present; otherwise it's absent.

We don't know how our graph might look, so we have to introduce n^2 variables to represent all edges:

```
> e_0, e_1, ..., e_m
```

We consider a vertex as present if and only if it has at least one present edge:

```
v_i <=> OR (e_0, e_1, ..., e_k)
```

Finally, let's introduce connectivity constraints. We can use [pseudo-boolean constraints](http://minisat.se/downloads/MiniSat+.pdf) to do this. Next constraint guarantees that if a vertex is present then it **must** have at least 5 edges present. Only than the function will evaluate to *True*.

```
min_degree_i <=> greater_than_equal (get_all_edges_from_vertex (v_i), min_value=5)
```

Next constraint ensures that all vertices must be present, except for any 3 of them (vertex connectivity). The same with edges:

```
vertices_connectivity <=> select_exact ( (v_0, ..., v_n), (vertices_num - 3) )
edges_connectivity <=> select_exact ( (e_0, ..., e_m), (edges_num - 4) )
```

Finally, we can pass a formula to SAT solver (e.g. [Glucose](http://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/)). Output will be a graph that satisfies all given constraints.

I'm not sure that my approach is the best, but I would suggest to explore it in more details. I didn't implement it myself, so my algorithm might have some drawbacks/bugs. My point is that if you don't know how to build a solution and you don't know how it might look then try to use constraints to find out that.